# Changing MacOS Location based on SSID - can't get script to run automatically

Tags: bash, macos, github, ssid

I'm trying to get [this GitHub project](https://github.com/rimar/wifi-location-changer) up and running on my Mac, for the purposes of automatically changing my network location when I switch physical location (based on the SSID I'm connected to). I have two problems I'm so far unable to resolve.

1. I've followed the instructions to update the appropriate location names, and associated SSID's, and it largely all works as it should. However, there's one SSID that has a space in the name, and when I connect to that SSID, it falls back to "Automatic" location as it did not find a matching SSID in the list. I have updated the script as per the suggestions below to put quote marks in all the places they are missing, but the issue appears to be in getting the SSID in the first place. The log file echoes the new SSID name, and if my SSID were `my wifi` it just echoes `New SSID Found: my`. So I likely just need to slightly change the line of code that gets the SSID (below), but I'm not sure how.

`SSID=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID:/ {print $2}')`

2. I've completed the automated installation (executed `./install.sh` on the appropriate directory), and it has placed all the files in the relevant places. However, it does not automatically run whenever I switch SSID's. I can double click on the executable at any point and it will run and select the correct location, but it doesn't execute automatically, which is the whole point of the exercise. Have I missed a step somewhere?

I'm extremely new to scripting on mac and GitHub in general; my previous experience is all on Windows. So I'm probably overlooking something really simple, but I just don't have the skills yet to work out where it is.

Running macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: Either single- or double-quotes around the SSID name should work (e.g. `SSID_Spacey="Network with spaces"`). Did you update the `Location_` list *and* the  `SSID_` list *and* both of the `case` statements?

Comment: The script at https://github.com/rimar/wifi-location-changer/blob/master/locationchanger has bugs in it. Try running it through http://shellcheck.net and correcting them... basically anywhere there is a `bash` variable with a $ in front of if, you'll need double quotes around it.

Comment: Yes, I updated the location list, SSID list and case statements. If I change the SSID to one without spaces it works, so it's just a matter of getting the correct SSID in the first place. I've also run the script through shellcheck as suggested by @MarkSetchell (thanks - good tool to know about) and tidied up the issues identified. I've since been able to narrow down the cause a little more, and edited my main post to contain the relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice sleuthing! It should work if you change the `awk` to use a colon and a space as the field separator:

```
SSID=$(AIRPORTTHING| awk -F ': ' '/ SSID:/ {print $2}')
```

Failing that, this should work too:

```
SSID=$(AIRPORTTHING| sed -n 's/^ *SSID: //p')
```

Comment: Thanks, that has resolved my first issue! Just need to get it executing automatically. Would I be better to start a separate thread with just that question?

Comment: Check if the script at `/usr/local/bin/locationchanger` matches what you have got debugged in the Terminal first. If not, update that.

Comment: Then check you have `~/Library/LaunchAgents/LocationChanger.plist`. Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/LocationChanger.plist` and maybe reboot.

Comment: Turns out both the automated install and manual install instructions are incorrect. I looked more closely at which files were supposed to be where - instead of creating `/usr/local/bin` and placing the `locationchanger` file there, it renamed the `locationchanger` file to `bin` and placed it in `/usr/local`. Once I created a `bin` folder and copied my debugged script into it, it started working with no further changes. My first experience with GitHub leaves a lot to be desired, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: It's not GitHub's fault, but this project will continue to not work very well if you don't file bug reports for the problems you found. Just sayin' ...