# Changing MacOS Location based on SSID - check current location before changing

Tags: bash, macos, notifications

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049628/changing-macos-location-based-on-ssid-cant-get-script-to-run-automatically/60070553#60070553) I received some assistance with getting [this script](https://github.com/rimar/wifi-location-changer) to work correctly. The script essentially sets my network location according to the SSID I'm connected to. This is now working, however, it generates a lot of nuisance notifications.

Every time my laptop joins a wifi network, the script runs, sets the network location, and gives me a notification. Since power nap periodically joins the wifi to check for emails/updates and what have you, after a long weekend I'll get dozens of identical notifications.

How can I modify the script so that it only send a notification if the network location is changed to something different, not just when the script runs? Can I somehow check the existing network location and only change it/trigger a notification if the "new" location is different to the "existing" location?

Again, I'm extremely new to scripting on mac and GitHub in general; my previous experience is all on Windows and largely self taught.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# automatically change configuration of Mac OS X based on location

# redirect all IO to a logfile
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log
exec &>/usr/local/var/log/locationchanger.log

# get a little breather before we get data for things to settle down
sleep 2


# get SSID
SSID=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I | sed -n 's/^ *SSID: //p')
echo $(date) "New SSID found: $SSID"

# LOCATIONS
LOCATION=
Location_Automatic="Automatic"
Location_Office="Office"
Location_Site="Site"

# SSIDS
SSID_Office="My Office SSID"
SSID_Site="My Mobile SSID"


# SSID -> LOCATION mapping
case $SSID in
    "$SSID_Office") LOCATION="$Location_Office";;
    "$SSID_Site"  ) LOCATION="$Location_Site";;

esac
    REASON="SSID changed to $SSID"


# Location_Automatic
if [ -z "$LOCATION" ]; then
    LOCATION="$Location_Automatic"
    REASON="Automatic Fallback"
fi

# change network location
scselect "$LOCATION"

case $LOCATION in
    "$Location_Automatic" )
        osascript -e 'display notification "Network Location Changed to Automatic" with title "Network Location Changed"'
    ;;

    "$Location_Office" )
        osascript -e 'display notification "Network Location Changed to Office" with title "Network Location Changed"'
    ;;

    "$Location_Site" )
        osascript -e 'display notification "Network Location Changed to Site" with title "Network Location Changed"'
    ;;

esac

echo "--> Location Changer: $LOCATION - $REASON"

exit 0
```

Comment: add a var last_location and compare with current location before printing message. set last_location when printing message

Comment: @alecxs thanks - only thing is that this will only track the last instance of the script changing the network location, it will not log if the network location is changed manually and then the script changes it back. Definitely better than what I've got now, but ideally I'd like to be able to check the actual current network location rather than just the last one the script changed it to

Comment: instead *echo* you can assign string to another var *msg* and compare with *last_msg* before printing *echo -e "$msg"* and set *last_msg="$msg"*

Comment: Both suggestions only work if (a) the new variable retains its value between script executions, and (b) the network location is not changed manually in between. For these reasons I'd prefer to check the actual network location to determine whether to retrigger the notification. It would also be good practice because I can prevent it from sending the "change network location" command to begin with, if the network location doesn't need changing. If I can't do that, I'll have to use one of those two options, but in that case I'll have to work out how to retain variables between script executions

Comment: for some reason i didn't realize this is not a daemon loop script sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/319902/os-x-how-to-get-the-current-network-location-inside-a-bash-function) explains how to get the current network location.

I added the following code to get the current network location before making any changes:

```
CurrLoc=$(scselect | awk '{if ($1=="*") print $3}' | sed 's/[()]//g')
```

And then a simple if statement to exit the script early if the evaluated "new" network location matched the existing one:

```
if [ "$CurrLoc" = "$LOCATION" ]
then
    exit 0
fi

# existing code to change network location and show notifications
```